# Is the sequence $\Big \{\cos\Big(\dfrac 12 \tan^{-1}\big(-\dfrac n2\big)^n\Big)\Big \}$ monotone ?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is the sequence $\Big \{\cos\Big(\dfrac 12 \tan^{-1}\big(-\dfrac n2\big)^n\Big)\Big \}$  monotone ? I can show that the sequence is convergent without any clue if it's monotone or not . Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since $\cos$ is even and monotonic on $(0,\pi]$, $\tan^{-1}(\frac{n}{2})^n$ is increasing (towards $\frac{\pi}{2}$) and $|\tan^{-1}(\frac{-n}{2})^n| = \tan^{-1}(\frac{n}{2})^n$.

So $\cos(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(-\frac{n}{2})^n)) = \cos(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(\frac{n}{2})^n)) $ with the inner function being monotone having values where $\cos$ is monotone is monotone.

Comment: How is $\cos(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(-\frac{n}{2})^n)) = \cos(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(\frac{n}{2})^n))$ ? As far as I can understand , it does not directly follow from " $\cos $ is even " ..

Comment: @SaunDev it follows from $\tan^{-1}$ being odd, which implies the last equality in the first paragraph of my answer.